# How to create a dll for a few classes without creating separate project file

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild

I have an existing project, but I want to generate a dll for only a subset of the total classes in this project using MSBuild.

I know I accomplish this by creating a `.csprj` file and inserting all the class filenames(that I want) and MSBuild can generate a dll for that `.csprj`. But I am not allowed to introduce any new changes in that project (i.e. I can't create a `.csprj` file in that project).

How can I create a dll using MSBuild that is composed of some of the files in the existing `.csprj`?

Note: i am using jenkins for continuous integration, the solution is expected to do something with jenkins to create a seperate dll of few files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use csc.exe (c# compiler) directly [Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx). If you need to build this dll each time you build main dll - you can add this as a post-build user task in your main project. If you need to build it once - just use it from command line. Syntax is trivial.

Comment: Your suggestion would modify the existing csprj which the author isn't allowed to change.

Comment: So you want to find a solution which will allow you to change nothing and get the result? You can create just a bat file which will invoke CSC.exe on special files, and run it each time you need to build new version of library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.....I am using Jenkins for continuous integration, can you please tell me how to achieve the dll creation for few files using that..

Comment: I did not use Jenkins, but as I said before - just create a batch file which will use csc.exe to generate required dll from specific files. After this you can use this batch file on CI server to generate it regularly.